# Package resolvconf 1.79ubuntu10.18.04.1 is broken

Tags: dns, resolvconf

Updating Ubuntu 18.04 resolvconf with version 1.79ubuntu10.18.04.1 breaks DNS record resolution.

Bug reference: [1819625](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1819625)

Answer (score -1):

Workaround till fixed by Ubuntu team:
Download resolvconf_1.79ubuntu10_all.deb

Install the previous version:

```
sudo dpkg --install resolvconf_1.79ubuntu10_all.deb
```

Prevent installing the broken version in the next upgrade:

```
echo "resolvconf hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```